# Understanding @input - from parent to child

Tags: angular, typescript, input, angular7, angular8

I try to learn Angular and now I'm at the `@Input` stage.

I have a main app and a child component. In `app.component.ts` I have a test variable. I want to pass this variable from `app.component.ts` to `child.component.ts`.

```
// app.component.ts:
export class AppComponent {
    test = 10;
}  

// child.component.ts:
export class ChildComponent {
    @Input() fromParent: number;
    childVar = fromParent + 5;

    show() {
        console.log(this.childVar);
    } //this should to show 15 in console...
}
```

Now, how can I do this?

Comment: Doesn't work this way, please read the docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property binding and event binding are the two core concepts in angular.

Components and Directives can be considered as defining your custom elements and attributes respectively.
  eg: h1 is a tag that's already defined in HTML but app-root is not. So we can consider angular component as a way to create custom element and directive as a custom attribute. (for now)

An attribute/tag become a child of another if that is used inside the other tag's component html.

Child can pass some data to parent via event binding.

Parent can pass some data to child viz property binding.

There should be some way to say the angular compiler that a variable inside a child can be accessed by the child (on the template) to denote that we use @Input() decorator to a property.

Answer (score 3):

Below you can find an example that illustrates the mechanism allowing a parent component to bind properties that a child component can have access to.

> Parent component template: **parent.component.html**

```
<child-component 
    [fromParent]="fromParent">
</child-component>
```

> Parent component class: **parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent {
  fromParent: string = 'String from parent';
}
```

> Child component class: **child.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

//...

export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() fromParent: string;
}
```

> Child component template: **child.component.html**

```
String from parent: {{ fromParent }}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `app.component.html` you call your **child component's** `selector` (assuming it is `child-app`) :

```
<child-app></child-app>
```

Then add what's declared as `@input()` to it and bind it to the value in the `AppComponent` (which is `test`):

```
<child-app [fromParent]="test" ></child-app>
```

Finally you should refactor your snippet to:

```
****child.component.ts:****

export class ChildComponent { // Here is not AppComponent
    @Input() fromParent: number;
    childvar: number;


    show() {
        this.childVar = this.fromParent + 5; // this op should be inside a method 
        console.log(this.childVar);
    } //this should to show 15 in console...
}
```

Comment: Thank you all!!! I don't know why they did this think so complicated. I think in Java is much more easy to do this between classes...

Comment: @Sebastian Welcome, :)

Answer (score 1):

> Simply put the property on the *child selector* in your ***app.component.html*** as follows -

```
<!-- replace element selector with yours -->
<app-child [fromParent]="test"></app-child>
```

> And you may **optionally** implement OnChanges interface in your ***child.component.ts***, so that it would be -

```
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() fromParent: number;
    childVar = fromParent + 5;

    ngOnChanges() { // this will be called automatically when updated by parent.
        console.log(this.childVar);
    }

    show() { // called on demand
        console.log(this.childVar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you place a child component, you initialize its variable. So, somewhere in the parents template you do this:

```
<app-child [fromParent]="test"></app-child>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*So what if the apples component is almost the same for each instance, but we need it to display a different description for each instance? We use Input .*  

  // app.component.html
<app-apple [description]="appleDescription"></app-apple>
```

**appleDescription can be any class property inside app.component.html.**

```
// apple.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
...
export class AppleComponent implements OnInit {
   @Input() description: string;
...
```

*Now, description is passed in by whomever the parent component is. In this case it’s app.component.html. Any value can be passed into [description] and description can be used anywhere inside of apple.component.html or apple.component.ts as if it were a regular class property that follows normal change detection.*

```
// apple.component.html
{{ description || 'Nothing has been typed yet...' }}
```